# Replace simple text in the end if line with sed

Tags: text-processing, sed

I have that text `#!/usr/bin/env python` and I want to replace `python` with `python3`  (without regex) but I want to make sure that this text in the end of line.

I tried this command:

`sed -i 's/python\n/python3\n/g' a.txt`

But it doesn't replace the text. I make sure with hex dump that after `python` there is 0x0a (\n)

What can I do please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `$` not `\n` to match end of line:

```
sed -i 's/python$/python3/' a.txt
```

You don't need the `g` modifier (there can only be one end of line per line) but you may wish to limit the replacement to the first line of the file, or to the line beginning with `#!`:

```
sed -i '/^#!/s/python$/python3/' a.txt
```

By default, sed reads its input line-by-line, so that the newline character itself is never included in the pattern buffer. However, `$` is the regular expression anchor denoting the end of line.

See [How sed Works](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/html_node/Execution-Cycle.html#Execution-Cycle)